# Automatic export from SAP GUI (no direct access to Database)

Tags: automation, export, sap-gui

I'm looking for making **automatic** exports (extractions) from SAP.

But there is some restraints :

- It's impossible to work with the SAP Support team on this subject
- I don't have direct access to SAP Database (Just a login/password for the SAP Gui)
- I want to computerize the action of a simple SAP User :

  -> Login to SAP Gui

  -> Access to the right menu (by name or transaction code)

  -> Put informations relating to the user (Site code, Department code, Material code, etc...)

  -> Put a dynamic range date (which could change every day)

  -> Extract data as a CSV file

The final objective is to build a job schedule (every days at 00:00 for example) which create an export file (with SAP Data) on a file server.

Every ideas are welcome (official or not).

Comment: The first question should be - why is it impossible to work with the SAP support team? Are you by chance trying to do anything that would be agains some rules you probably should know, but don't?

Comment: What data do you want to extract? If you bring more details, we can better address your problem.

Comment: It's a political problem : one year (or two) to send the problem to the SAP Support and how many money ? 

I want to extract delivery informations : 
Piece_id | Order Date | Delivery Date | ... 

We already do this export manually with the SAP Gui Export menu. But we want to do it automaticaly.

Comment: I definitely agree with Sarah: contacting SAP Support couldn't be treated neither as a "perfect shot", nor a solution at all. Ticket resolution can take months or years, not days.